# Sum one column based on a pattern in another AWK

Tags: awk

My input file is as follows:

```
scaffold100 115050  116050  1000    115050  124008  2
scaffold100 1167811 1168811 1000    1167811 1568661 0
scaffold100 151385  152385  1000    151385  193501  4
scaffold100 1585695 1586695 2000    1585695 1644609 5
scaffold100 1654143 1655143 2000    1654143 1673659 3
scaffold100 1711976 1712976 2000    1711976 1843374 1
```

I am learning AWK and I want to use it to sum column 7 based on column 4.
That is if column 4 is equal to 1000, then sum up 2+0+4=6 and print.

I am tyring this code but I don't understand what I am doing wrong:

```
awk '{if($4==1000) {sum+=$7;n++}END{print sum}}' file
```

Comment: Read the book Effective Awk Programming, 4th Edition, by Arnold Robbins. Start with that and then you won't be confused about awk syntax and write scripts like you've posted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this `awk`:

```
awk '$4==1000{sum+=$7}END{print sum+0}' file
```

Output:

```
$ awk '$4==1000{sum+=$7}END{print sum+0}' a
6
```

Another `awk`:

```
awk '{arr[$4]+=$7}END{for(val in arr){print val,arr[val]}}' file
```

Output:

```
$ awk '{arr[$4]+=$7}END{for (val in arr) {print val,arr[val]}}' a
2000 9
1000 6
```

Answer (score 1):

Your opening and closing curly braces are a bit messed up.

```
$ cat data 
scaffold100 115050  116050  1000    115050  124008  2
scaffold100 1167811 1168811 1000    1167811 1568661 0
scaffold100 151385  152385  1000    151385  193501  4
scaffold100 1585695 1586695 2000    1585695 1644609 5
scaffold100 1654143 1655143 2000    1654143 1673659 3
scaffold100 1711976 1712976 2000    1711976 1843374 1
$ awk 'BEGIN{sum=0}{if($4==1000) {sum+=$7}}END{print sum}' data
6
```

or

```
$awk '$4==1000 {sum+=$7} END{print sum}' data
6
```